# no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: postfix, freebsd, dovecot

I am running freebsd 10.1  with postfix and Dovecot.

In the mail logs for postfix, I get this error:

> fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Below is dovecot log errors:

```
Error: auth: environment corrupt; missing value for DOVECOT_
auth: Fatal: unsetenv(RESTRICT_SETUID) failed: Bad address
```

In my dovecot config I do have

```
auth_mechanism= plain login
```

This is set. I don't understand where the no mechanisms error is coming from.

What are the possible issues. I do have the auth_mechanism= plain login set in dovecot.

Postfix is properly setup. Does anyone got any possible ideas?

Comment: is there chroot?

Comment: No chroot... I  installed via the default way.

Comment: I had a working e-mail server system. I had to upgrade from freebsd 8.1 to freebsd 10.1 gradually. I upgraded all software. It at first broke but then I fixed it.  However, the e-mail system didn't use ssl or any encryption. Then recently around april. I got a hacker that was trying to break in. I quickly turn it off and added security to my server like firewalls and other things.  I then enabled it and started to install ssl. I upgraded postfix and dovecot the last software packages. So, the last time it worked was in May. I used ssl and everything worked. However, I then upgraded to 2.3

Comment: to version 2.3 dovecot and same with postfix. Postfix was fine. Yet, dovecot wasn't working properly. I then started to monkey around with both. I made some changes for the better.  Right now  I can send out e-mail and receive e-mail.  I tested via gmail and the e-mails sent never gets anything coming back. The only problem I have is logging into the mail server to look at the e-mails in my inbox. The errors in the log points out the authentication process is broken.  It doesn't give any specific information. Other then there's no value set.  I had to previously make changes to dovecot config.

Comment: changes to dovecot config.. like for instance  socket listen that part had to change to unix_listener..etc there's been some major syntax changes between versions 1.0 to 2.0. I had to make those changes. It looks like the only problem is how the authentication system is setup. I think I need to change the configs for it... to the right syntax for dovecot v 2.0 and above.  I cannot find any material to indicate that this is the problem. I read the manual and it only talks about setting mechanisms...even though I have it set. I don't know if I need to set it to ANONYMOUS or external??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, SASL authentication is supported by SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism or EXTERNAL, if you want to use external authenticator.

Desired mechanism should be listed in the `auth_mechanism` parameter along with `plain login`

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms

Comment: What do you mean? I just want a plain login format. I have ssl encryption for smtp and imaps. The logs show everything else working but the authentication process is broken. The errors above show as if I never specified the auth_mechanisms variable....which I have in Dovecot.  Dovecot is used for imap and postfix is used for smtp.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by external? What is the parameter for?  I would love to use a method that is the most secure. However, for now just want to clear the error messages and have a working system using ssl.  Plus what is the ANONYMOUS parameter?  I  have imap access via my website. So, everyone can look at their e-mail via my website. I want to permit only certain ip addresses or blocks to be able to use a client to access the imap service. This block should only be allowed to access one account... or whatever accounts they created.

Comment: In my  /user/local/lib/sasl2 I have many .so files but there's only one .conf file which is called Sendmail.conf. There's no smptd.conf file.  The Sendmail.conf contains only "pwcheck_method: saslauthd". That is about it.  Do you think I need to create a smptd.conf file?